# Why does it take so long for SQL Management Studio to connect?

Tags: sql-server, ms-sql

Considering that Microsoft SQL Server is not, technically, a slow database management system, I keep wondering why it often/usually takes such a long time for SQL Management Studio to connect.

This happens even when nobody else is accessing the database server and when Management Studio runs on the same machine as SQL Server.

Plus SQL Management Studio often takes a very long time to do something, even just displaying a login's permissions can take several minutes on database servers otherwise unused.

Is there some obvious explanation?

Comment: How long is "so long"? 2 seconds, 20 seconds or 200 seconds?

Comment: Do you have any odd plugins? Every server I try to connect to takes under 2 seconds on my work network.

Comment: @Bevan for me, minutes to connect to `localhost`... it's truly frustrating. (YMMV) And it started at some recent point in time, it was never like this before.

Comment: @Bevan, for me it takes 50 seconds to start. When I click the icon until something shows up it is 50 seconds which in my opinion is way too much time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds stupid but I had a problem of a very slow SQL Server Management Studio and this trick solved it:

- Open Internet Explorer
- Go to Tools -> Internet option
- Open the "Advanced" tab
- Uncheck "Check for server certificate revocation (requires restart)"

This trick is only effective if the computer where your SQL Server Management Studio is installed is NOT connected to Internet.
Only doing that solved my problem. Maybe it will solve yours.

Comment: Oddly enough this seems to improve things a bit. But the 32/64 bit issue mentioned below could also be right. I'll accept this answer and upvote the other.

Comment: In my case, the server wasn't connected to the Internet so it couldn't perform any security check, so it didn't change much, except after that I didn't have to wait for the timeout :). 
But I agree this is not a good idea on a server that can perform this check.

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me: [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is too Slow](https://web.archive.org/web/20180312183339/http://www.virtualobjectives.com.au/sqlserver/ssms_slow.htm)

> In a corporate environment it is not uncommon for Microsoft SQL Server
>   Management Studio (SSMS) for SQL Server 2005 to take over 45 seconds
>   to start as well as lags and delays when opening various windows and
>   dialog boxes from within the application. If you are experiencing this
>   issue, then a quick fix is to add an entry in your HOSTS. file that
>   points crl.microsoft.com to 127.0.0.1
>
> - Exit SSMS
> - Press the keys [Win] + [R]
> - Enter the following..
>
>   ```
>   notepad %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.
>   ```
> - Append the following..
>
>   ```
>   127.0.0.1    crl.microsoft.com
>   ```
> - Save the file.
> - Start SSMS (ah! much better)

Comment: My god, it's bizzare...

Comment: Since `crl` stands for "Certificate Revocation List", this is also non-ideal from a security point of view (see the comments on the accepted answer).

Comment: For me this seems to have taken the delay from 30++ seconds down to < 5 seconds, but still slow.

Comment: People have it so wrong... Business practices are not the reason to hate Microsoft.  This is the reason, this right here... this and all the other arcane nonsense to get just about any standard application running well on their stack.

Comment: Trying this in early 2021 got the time down for me from 30 seconds to 7 seconds, on a superfast server. I still think its disgustingly slow, this is on a new/big server with huge processing power, SSD disks, 128GB ram and 10 gigabit internet connection. I suspect that MS is phoning home to send your data back since there's really nothing else that would take so long other than waiting for someone else's server.

Answer (score 3):

by default, when connecting to a local server, the network protocol used is shared memory.
This can be quite slow sometimes.

I was experiencing the same speed issue when connecting to a similiarly specced box locally, but not remotely.

Do you get the same slowdown if you specify the TCP/IP network protocol when connecting?

**EDIT**
Also, according to Microsoft, this may be an issue caused by Management Studio being 32bit and being run on a 64bit OS.
See here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906892

Comment: So Microsoft recommends running it on a 32-bit OS.  Not exactly a practical suggestion. *rolling my eyes*

Answer (score 3):

Possible broken IPv6 implementation?  Are you running dual-stack?  We are and have had this problem before.  IPv6 is tried first, and if there's any configuration errors it'll eventually fail to IPv4.

Answer (score 3):

SSMS is attempting to check with Microsoft for the default root certificate, even though it does not us it. If you are using a proxy server use either proxycfg or netsh to set the system proxy settings. Close and then open SSMS and the time to load will be greatly reduced.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Julien N 's answer above, I fixed the problem (a 10-second delay when running a query the first time) by un-ticking:

"Check for Publisher's certificate revocation"

in Internet Explorer advanced options.
No restart required.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to disable the Hyper-V NIC:

[image]

Simply right-click and then click `disable`

Update 2021: Problem came back. This time it was a [reverse DNS entry](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104395/8200) that solved it.

Comment: This was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that my machine name was longer than is allowed by NETBIOS (15 characters). Once I shortened it, navigating SSMS became lightning fast.

Windows warns you if you try to set your machine name to longer than 15 characters -- I guess I should have heeded the warning!

Answer (score 1):

My colleague has the exact behavior as you on his PC. He was using SQL Server Management Studio of 2005. He solved installing the new version that comes with SQL Server 2008.

If you notice that this problem happen only on your PC I suggest you to try uninstall and re-install the whole Microsoft SQL Server suite.

Comment: This happens to me with both SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: ...and all the way up to SSMS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a Name Resolution problem? If the SQL Server engine is on the same machine, try using (local) as the name or even 127.0.0.1 (or the IP address of the machine). Netbios over TCP/IP and/or deficient WINS/DNS can lead to slow connecting times.

Also make sure that the server has enough memory to operate. SQL Server can work well under 512 MB ram, but the performance degrades very fast.

There shouldn't be a delay longer than 5 secs when connecting to a server. (Less if local).

Comment: No. It connects to ".". The servers in question are 64 bit and have 8 GB and more.

Answer (score 1):

I added sqlservr.exe to the exception list of the windows firewall on SQL server 2005.
Result: very quick respons!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was not every time, but when it did, it would take 10 min to get back even my connection box. So I looked at Configuration manager and disabled shared memory. Works like charm every time !!

Comment: A little more detail such as which version, navigation from the app to this setting, etc. would be helpful.

Comment: This worked for me. To do this run the SQL Server Configuration Manager and disable "Shared Memory" under Network Configuration / Protocols

Answer (score 0):

I was having kind of same problem where Views folder was taking long time to expand. Other folders including databases or tables were OK. All of the recommendations above didn't work in my case.
What worked for me is the user had sysdamin role, I removed the sysadmin role and give it back and everything start working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

yups this worked for me.
running from an elevated cmd prompt:
reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32

Comment: What are side effects of this?

Answer (score 0):

```
reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32
```

Try this on admin cmd
and agaiin try to install.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using SQL Express, check that the total size of your databases does not exceed 10 GB (limitation for SQL Express 2012).

Comment: If the size exceeds the limitation, would the result be just slow performance?